# Python, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

My project structure:

```
project
    main.py
    modules
        client.py
        server.py
        find_host_ip.py
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\...\main.py", line 1, in <module>
from modules import client, server
File "C:\...\modules\client.py", line 2, in <module>
from find_host_ip import Network
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'find_host_ip'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **full path** to module, or you can **place modules in root directory**, and you don't have to change the code:

```
from /modules/find_host_ip import Network
```